# How should HTTP Post look like for saving model and associated model data?

Tags: php, cakephp, post, http-post, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp 2.4.5. I have 2 tables with a one-to-many relationship. Table B belongs to Table A.

I want a controller in Table A that can save records in Table A and Table B. The controller code should be simple and looks like this;

```
public function add_tableA($id=null)
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->layout = null ;
        $this->TableA->create();                
        $this->TableA->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
    }
}
```

My problem comes when trying to send the right HTTP POST format to the controller.

I tried to HTTP POST the data format below but it fails.

```
data[TableA][field1] = field1_value
data[TableA][field2] = field2_value
data[TableB][field1] = field1_value
data[TableB][field2] = field2_value
```

Then, I try to HTTP POST the data format below, at least TableA fields are populated.

```
data[TableA][field1] = field1_value
data[TableA][field2] = field2_value
```

How should the HTTP POST data format look like if I want to create rows for both tables?

Comment: How does your form look like?

Comment: I am not using a HTML form. Not using cakephp views. I am going to use Cakephp purely as a REST API server. I am using python to directly send a HTTP Post. This is why I need to know the data format to be sent in the HTTP Post.

Comment: I think, you should use saveAssociated() instead of saveAll(). Check the data structure at its official site.

Comment: @ Vikash Pathak: I tried saveAssociated() but it still does not work.

Comment: For example, TableB belongsTo TableA, I think in this case you can't save from TableA, did you try to save from TableB? You have to add relation to tableA where `TableA hasMany TableB`. Do you have that in your model?

Comment: Yes. I have verified that. I can also cake bake all my tables properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

and example for saveAssociated:

```
$data = array(
    'Article' => array('title' => 'My first article'),
    'Comment' => array(
        array('body' => 'Comment 1', 'user_id' => 1),
        array('body' => 'Comment 2', 'user_id' => 12),
        array('body' => 'Comment 3', 'user_id' => 40),
    ),
);
```

So, in your case post something like

```
data[TableA][field1] = field1_value
data[TableA][field2] = field2_value
data[TableB][0][field1] = field1_value
data[TableB][0][field2] = field2_value
data[TableB][1][field1] = field1_value
data[TableB][1][field2] = field2_value
etc
```

and:

```
$this->TableA->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save it like that you need to have:

```
data[TableB][TableA_id] = 'id of data saved be to TableA';
```

for TableB data to be saved. So I think you need to first save TableA:

```
$dataA = $this->TableA->save('data for TableA');
if (!$dataA) {
   $data['TableB']['TableA_id'] = $this->TableA->id;
   $this->TableA->TableB->save('data array for TableB');
}
```

Comment: It may work but it is not as neat as the answer given by theotherdy. But still many thanks.