# cakePHP saveAssociated belongsTo

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Does saveAssociated work with belongsTo models? I have a **`Donor`** model which belongs to **`User`** model. This means that `user_id` is stored in the `Donor` model. I am trying to use `saveAssociated()` to save donor/user data in one call. However this does not seem to work

Hers is what I tried :

```
 $this->request->data['User'][0]['role'] = 'donor'; //tried without the `[0]`
 $this->request->data['User'][0]['activation_secret'] =  $activation_secret;
 if($this->Donor->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))){
     //success message 
 }
```

I got around this by doing like so:

```
$user = $this->Donor->User->save($this->request->data);
if(!empty($user)){
    $this->request->data['Donor']['user_id'] = $this->Donor->User->getLastInsertId();
}
if($this->Donor->save($this->request->data)){
// success message
}
```

IS this the right way to do it? Or am I missing something ?

**[EDIT]**

My form follows this pattern

```
<?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Donor');
            echo $this->Form->input('name', array('id' => 'name','div' => 'inline-input'));
            echo $this->Form->input('surname', array('id' => 'surname','div' => 'inline-input'));
 ?>
```

NB. The associated model data to be saved, is hardcoded as shown above in the save action.

Comment: How does your form looks like? Also take a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346721/how-should-http-post-look-like-for-saving-model-and-associated-model-data)

Comment: As suggested in the answer  in the link/question you provided,  I tried using the second array key,but no luck

Comment: @skywalker Aswell as you described in your answer to that question, I also think that since the table Im trying to save from, is the one with the belongsTo association (making it not the main model), and therefore need to save associated data first.. if this makes any sense.. But I might be wrong, which is exactly  why I asked on SO :)

Comment: Just this thing: are you saving new user with donor? I presume not, so you can do something like this: list all users and add that to your form in one select.

Comment: Indeed I am saving new user_account for a donor who just donated. This account will be inactive until the donor decides to activate it by setting up username and password.

Comment: In that case, the way you are doing it is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$this->request->data['User']['role'] = 'donor';
$this->request->data['User']['activation_secret'] =  $activation_secret;

unset($this->Donor->validate['user_id']); // This might solve your problem

if($this->Donor->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))){
    //success message 
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought but it did not work for me(for some reason). The id inside the User table would be just 'id'(following cake's conventions).

Comment: I'm sorry, your're right. It's the foreign_key that needs to be skipped for validation when using saveAssociated() or saveMany(). Edited my answer. Maybe try that?

Comment: Darn I thought that would be it once you mentioned it, but still no! Would have to work with my work around for now! I just prefer short/clean code